# How to find a maximum of multiple numbers using a tempate?

Tags: c++, templates

How should I write a template class to find a maximum of several numbers?

It should work like so:

```
Maximum<5,4,3>::value == 5
Maximum<12,4,3>::value == 12
Maximum<5,4,3,23,2,3,34,343,3434,343,6,56,45,456,2>::value == 3434
```

Comment: Not possible. There is no such syntax as `===`.

Comment: sorry, wrong habit due to too much js coding

Comment: Sorry :( and thanks :)

Comment: Also, what have you tried? Have you failed at anything specific? Answers showing research efforts (maybe failed attempts) with clear problem statements tend to attract more love and upvotes.

Comment: i have always done template coding like Maximum<int, int>; not like Maximum<5,7>. So really clueless. Also no such thing i could find with my googling capability on internet :(

Comment: Why not just use `std::max`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
template <int first, int second, int ... rest> 
class maximum : 
    public maximum<std::max(first, second), rest...> {};

template <int first, int second> 
class maximum<first, second> : 
    public integral_constant<int, std::max(first, second)> {};
```

Online [here](https://ideone.com/QZsSpp)

**Update**

The first class is the generic class that accepts three or more integers. It will then find the maximum of the two first inputs and then recursively inherit where the first template parameter is that said maximum. This is carried out until there is only two template parameters left.

The second class accepts exactly two template parameters. It then finds the maximum of those. It inherits from [std::integral_constant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) which defines the member `value`.

For the second class we need to write `class maximum<first, second>` since it is a specialized version of the first class, i.e., It takes exactly two inputs.

Comment: Some explaination please. Or you can give some link so that after reading that, i can understand this. Why at some place it is like " maximum :  " and at some place like "maximum<first, second> : " ?  What is integral_constant doing there? From where and how ::value gets executed?\

Answer (score 3):

With C++14 you can just use [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max):

```
std::max({5,4,3,23,2,3,34,343,3434,343,6,56,45,456,2}); // == 3434
```

Wrapped into a struct:

```
template <int... ints>
struct maximum {
    static constexpr int value = std::max({ints...});
};
```

[<kbd>On Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1a6d05a1fe57df7)

Comment: This one is neat.

Comment: Meta programming just isn't what it used to be :-)